# ListView SelectedIndices vs CheckedIndices: why Clear method missing with CheckedIndices property?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

I have a already-written `WinForm` code (compiled with .NET 4.5) where I need to make some modifications.

In particular I have some `ListView` objects where I have enabled check boxes by setting the related `CheckBoxes` property to `True`.
Therefore I've changed everywhere inside the code the use of `listview.SelectedItems` property with `listview.CheckedItems` property, but I still have some problems to understand the differences between the `SelectedIndices` vs the `CheckedIndices` property: why there isn't a `Clear` method for the `ListView.CheckedIndices` property?
From [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindexcollection.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) I understand that the `Clear` method just "clear all the selected items", so why it can't also clear all the "checked" items? Is there any alternative or workaround to this? Or maybe am I just missing an equivalent method to use with "checked" items instead of the "selected" ones?

**Edit: added sample code to clear what I'm asking for**

I had this kind of code:

```
ListView listViewDays, listViewDaysNumbers; // Initialized in standard "InitializeComponent" method

listViewDays.ItemSelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    listViewDaysNumbers.SelectedIndices.Clear();
    // do something else
};

listViewDaysNumbers.ItemSelectionChanged += (s, e) =>
{
    listViewDays.SelectedIndices.Clear();
    // do something else
};
```

Now I need to use the "Checked" status:

```
ListView listViewDays, listViewDaysNumbers; // Initialized in standard "InitializeComponent" method

listViewDays.ItemCheck += (s, e) =>
{
    listViewDaysNumbers.CheckedIndices.Clear(); // "Clear" method doesn't exist!
    // do something else
};

listViewDaysNumbers.ItemCheck += (s, e) =>
{
    listViewDays.CheckedIndices.Clear(); // "Clear" method doesn't exist!
    // do something else
};
```

Comment: selected items are highlighted items f.e. by clicking on them, checked items are items which have a checked checkbox. imo, you have to use a `for each loop` and uncheck each item within the loop. another hint: there is also the `CheckedListBox` class its bit more comfortable but you also have to do it there within a loop.

Comment: @Koryu: thank you - I had already thought about the `for-each` loop but I was hoping there was something "clearer", like a `Clear` method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I had already thought about the for-each loop

Not *everything* in .NET has a convenience method, this one doesn't.  Something to be said for Microsoft adding one however, a for-each loop is not the correct solution.  Keep in mind that when you iterate the collection and uncheck items, you are also *modifying* the collection.  That never turns out well.

So you shouldn't use a for-each loop.  Technically you can do it with the for(;;) loop, but you have to iterate backwards.  I usually prefer a while loop instead as it exposes the why-are-you-doing-this reason best:

```
    while (listView1.CheckedItems.Count > 0) {
        listView1.CheckedItems[0].Checked = false;
    }
```

If you find this too grating then a for-each loop can be made to work, you however have to make a copy of the list.  One that cannot be modified by the loop:

```
    foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.CheckedItems.OfType<ListViewItem>().ToArray()) {
        item.Checked = false;
    }
```

If you are doing this to prevent an item from getting checked then the easier way is:

```
    private void listView1_ItemChecked(object sender, ItemCheckedEventArgs e) {
        e.Item.Checked = false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and for show me different ways to reach my goal. I think I will put a `while` loop inside my code, it perfectly fits my needs.